# Tensorflow Get a Number of a Tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensor

I have a random Search Problem. I need the hyperparameter.

```
z_mean = Dense(units=hp.Int('unitsBottle',min_value=8,max_value=48,step=8))(h)
latentVariable = hp.get('unitsBottle')
z_log_var = Dense(units=latentVariable)(h)
```

latentVariable is a tensor. I can print it:

```
tf.Tensor(16, shape=(), dtype=int32)
```

But I need the number 16. Not as a tensor. As an integer number (scalar), so that I can put it into

```
z = Lambda(sampling, 
            output_shape=(latenteVariable,))([z_mean, 
            z_log_var, latenteVariable])
```

How can I only get the number?

Answer (score 4):

It is as simple as calling `int()` on the tensor:

```py
>>> tensor = tf.constant(16)
>>> print(tensor)
tf.Tensor(16, shape=(), dtype=int32)

>>> int(tensor)
16

>>> tensor.numpy()
16
>>> print(type(tensor.numpy()))
<class 'numpy.int32'>
```

Comment: Thank you. I hoped this was the problem. The problem must be somewhere else.

Comment: @user8020627 what's the problem?

Comment: It is more difficult. I have to open a new question. For unknown reasons choosing a global variable leads to 3 layers .. choosing a local variable leads to 8 layers in tensorflow.

Comment: Then, please accept Ynjxsjmh's answer as the right answer to close this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Using `.numpy()` is more intuitive as mentioned by **@Ynjxsjmh**. However, we can also use `eval` on the tensor to get the values.

```
from tensorflow.keras.backend import eval 

one = tf.constant(8)
two = tf.constant(8)
product = tf.add(one, two)

eval(one), eval(two), eval(product)
(8, 8, 16)
```